# MissingSchema error while test Django via Pytest and Requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, pytest, pytest-django

Try to make simple test admin page via python-requests

```
import requests
from django.urls import reverse


def test_admin():
     resp = requests.get(reverse('admin:index'))
     assert resp.status_code == 200
```

but got unexpected error

```
    def test_admin():
>       resp = requests.get(reverse('admin:index'))

src/users/tests/test_user_admin.py:6: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
venv1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py:72: in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
venv1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py:58: in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
venv1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:494: in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
venv1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:437: in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
venv1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py:305: in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

>           raise MissingSchema(error)
E           requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/admin/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///admin/?

venv1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py:379: MissingSchema
```

List of installed packages

```
pytest==3.3.2
requests==2.18.4
pytest-django==3.1.2
django==1.10.2
```

Read a lot of docs and manual but can't find solution.
Test with different `pytest.ini`, `manage.py`, `wsgi.py` and `settings.py`
Simple tests `assert 200==200` work properly. 
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`request.build_absolute_uri()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri):

```
 resp = requests.get(request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('admin:index')))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, `requests` requires a url with schema (http, https, ftp etc).

The problem is that `reverse` returns a relative path (eg `/admin/index`) but `requests` needs a full url including a schema (eg `http://localhost/admin/index`).

If you insist on using `reverse('admin:index')` rather than hardcoding the full url in the test, you will need to prepend `http://localhost:<port>/` (or whatever is the correct host in your case) to whatever `reverse('admin:index')` returns.